# spaces around CSS page header

Tags: css, html, header

[Page in question](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8740721/newstevesite/rehearsals/prices.html)
Trying to get the div containing the page header to move right to the top of the page.
I copied the code from this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/cqnUW/) i found in the solution to a similar problem but did not receive the same results

CSS
    body {background-color:#848484;}

```
#header{width:100%; background: blue;}
#headercontent{margin: 0 auto; width: 200px;}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="headercontent">
        <h1>Header text</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the margin from `<h1>` and `<body>`:

```
h1, body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h1, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding :0px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your page itself has padding or margins.  Add this to your style sheet:

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

css of `#headercontent`

just leave `float: right;` , delete the rest of the css. and you will see the headercontent to be on top-right of the page. proof is below.

[image]